# How to show left right icon whenever there is scroll

Tags: angularjs, gridview, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am using angular-material in my project. 
I have requirement in which I have to show left and right arrow automatically that will indicate there is scroll horizantally.
as you can see in the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use for it one of the angular carousel modules. Like [this](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-carousel).

Or one of the [list](http://ngmodules.org/tags/carousel)